# How I can emulate a storage failure at s3 in my unit test?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, phpunit, laravel-10

I have a service that uploads a file into s3:

```
class MyService
{
  public function uploadFile(SomeModel $m, UplaodFile $f)
  {
    $filename = md5(uniqid()).$file->getClientOriginalName();
    $status = Storage::disk('s3')->put($filename,fopen($file->getPathname(),'r'));
    
    if(!$status){
       throw new RuntimeException('Could not upload File');
    }
    // Do dome extra stuff here
  }
}
```

And I want in my unit test to test that an exception is thrown:

```
public function testUploadFileFails()
{
   Storage::fake('s3');
   Storage::shouldReceive('s3')
            ->once()
            ->andReturnNull();
   Storage::shouldReceive('put')->andReturn(false);
   // Assertion go here
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Failed asserting that exception of type "Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException" matches expected exception "RuntimeException". Message was: "Received Mockery_2_Illuminate_Filesystem_FilesystemManager::disk(), but no expectations were specified" at
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:355
/var/www/html/app/Services/UploadFileForClient.php:29
/var/www/html/tests/Unit/Services/UploadFileForClientTest.php:59
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:177
.
```

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to mock the disk as well:

```
public function testUploadFileFails()
{
   Storage::fake('s3');
   Storage::shouldReceive('disk')->with('s3')->andReturnSelf();
   Storage::shouldReceive('put')->andReturn(false);
   // Assertions go here
}
```

As you can see I mock disk as like this:

```
Storage::shouldReceive('disk')->with('s3')->andReturnSelf();
```

Instead of:

```
   Storage::shouldReceive('s3')
            ->once()
            ->andReturnNull();
```